# mdbootstrap not working properly in angularjs

Tags: angular

I am working angular cli 7 .i am importing mdbootstrap for UI. no more errors in my console. but it is not working properly.

[image]

Comment: Have you added css and js files in angular.json configuration?

Comment: "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
   "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
   "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss",
 "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
   "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"

Comment: if added these files, code seems fine to me. Just stop and re-run your application after clearing cache `npm cache clean -f`

Comment: Could you please edit your post to clarify if you are using angularjs or angular (in this case 7)? It is unclear. Thank you

Comment: This question might sound crazy, but do you use MDB jQuery or MDB Angular? I'm asking because a lot of new users tries to use integrate MDB jQuery with Angular while the edit dedicated to Angular is available too